# libxml2, xcode 4 (MGTwitter)

Tags: ios, xcode4, mgtwitterengine

I have an that is working well with xcode 3.x and I have tryed to work with it in xcode 4, to prepare the app to iOS 5.

When i try to Build, i get a lot of errors, like:
libxml/xmlreader.h: no such file or directory.

I've tryed a few things i found on google, but no success.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve it.

just changed the header to "/usr/include/libxml2"

And the Optimization level (all of them) to: "Fastest,Smallest [-Os]"